# Hiding drop down values without affecting functionality

Tags: c#, winforms

In my application I am trying to hide the values in my drop down list while it carries out the required functionality. As shown below you can see the drop down showing a value. The values are being pulled from a database.

[image]

When selected it would show the values below:

[image]

I would prefer if the values are not shown. Meaning I would want the dropdown values to not be shown but still carry out the fill operation as shown above.

So to explain more clearly, My comboBox which contains the value "123456789" would pass the values "P10434" and "Jev Pharma" to the respective textBoxes below respectively.Instead of showing my dropdown values while typing(auto suggest currently does this) I would instead want the dropdown list to not suggest any values at all. Meaning once I type "1234567..." it would not show any values int he comboBox but rather accept the info being typed in and pass the corresponding values from the database to the texboxes below.

I have tried changing the properties of the comboBox by removing append and suggest but the functionality is different. It no longer fills the data but instead just allows typing of a value. I am not sure how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167616/discussion-on-question-by-jevon-hiding-drop-down-values-without-affecting-functi).

Answer (score 1):

Set the properties as follows:

```
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Append;
        comboBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
        comboBox1.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
```

This will append the suggestions when typing without showing the list.
You can handle the appropriate event per your requirement to fill your textboxes.